# Problem with BLDC motor drive using PWM

Tags: pwm, driver, brushless-dc-motor, three-phase

We are trying to speed control a BLDC 48V 500W hub motor using hall sensors. We are using IRF540N MOSFETs with IR2112 gate drivers and Arduino as MCU. We implemented the 3 phase inverter and in testing the following happens:

1. As we start the motor at 12 volts with 5 volts applied to the gates the motor starts normally and as we increase the voltage the speed increases and so the current.
2. The motor does not start normally as we start it from high voltage 30V for example.
3. With any use of PWM signal on the gate the high side mosfets burns.
4. When we use 48 volts 12Ah battery all the MOSFETs in the driver burns.

The below circuit is one phase from our inverter

[image]

Updated the below curve is the DC bus current at no load. At first we have a 6A spikes but it lasts for a very short time.

[image]

Comment: There is so much to talk about. But bottom line would be "just get a normal servo drive".

Comment: Sadly we have to design the driver circuit ,, and we only have a problem with the PWM only ,,

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: @Osama That's a really horrendous schematic. Your computer might be okay with it since it has no feelings, but we who you are presenting the schematic to are actually humans (believe it or not).

Comment: @Gregory Kornblum ,, we test the motor without using the PWM and it worked fine but problems start to appear as we try to use the PWM

Comment: What do you understand about ideal commutation? and non-ideal shoot thru errors with causes and cures using dead-band control.

Comment: @ Harry Svensson ,, this photo was a screen shot from eagle CAD i just tried to present the general components but you are right it's not a nice schematic to present the design , i will post a more clear and detailed schematic ,, thank you for the feedback

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75 ,, I have an idea about the commutation in the BLDC motor control as we change the phase voltage according to the motor position but as for the dead-band control it's the first time to hear about it ,, i will start reading about it as it mayy help me understand my problem better ,, thank you for your respond

Comment: Osama, you should first start with proper mosfet driving. No, first find a real servo and see what it does and what components are used. Learn from others. Then- proper gate driving. Trust me, it takes years to build a descent servo.

Comment: http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridges-the-basics/

Comment: "With any use of PWM signal on the gate the high side mosfets burns" - which FET(s) are you applying the PWM to, and what frequency is the PWM? Please show the HIN and LIN drive waveforms for a full (6 step) electrical cycle.

Comment: BRuce is right, normally one uses low side for PWM and high side for direction for a full bridge. but this is a half bridge./

Comment: @Bruce Abbott ,, Thank you for your response ,, i am applying the PWM at the 3 high side mosfets at frequency of 20kHz ,, i will update the question with the wave form soon

Comment: @ Tony Stewart. EE since '75,, i am using the pwm at the high side mosfets not the low side.. is this a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there is a delay shutting off the current from one switch after the other complementary switch was turned on then there is a "shoot-thru" condition where there is a momentary short circuit current surge across the power supply thru the pair of switches.  This commutation of "make-before-break" is fixed by timing control of each switch gate drive to allow both to be off for some x microseconds period, usually dependent on the T=L/R ratio.  This is also called dead-time control.

Normally the diode//R attempts to turn OFF the gate faster than turn ON to assist in increasing deadtime but depending on Vgs slew rate, gate capacitance, source impedance, load inductance, ESR, RdsOn and L/R ratio, there are many contributors to delayed turn off.  **A simple way is to increase the value of the parallel Gate R but this has its limits with PWM frequency and gate capacitance.**

More basics.

http://www.modularcircuits.com/blog/articles/h-bridge-secrets/h-bridges-the-basics/

Comment: Thank you for your answer ,, i tried the Dead time delay but i still have the problem that the high side burns when using PWM however every thing works fine when commutating with a constant 5V signal at the gates,,

Comment: Ensure high side Vgs is >2.5x to 3x Vgs(th) so low RdsOn is obtained.  This is Vb.  If it is not a shootthru power dissipation issue then it may be a static I^2RdsOn issue?

Comment: compare DCR of phase coil to RdsOn of Q1. Consider adding a Rsense 0.077 Ohms and compare voltage drop with FET. I predict DCR of motor is 500 mΩ

Comment: I predict DCR of motor is 500 mΩ  so during full surge start, FET is dissipating 8W. Do you have soft start on PWM?

Comment: using pwm on gate signal burn the mosfets so i can not try soft start untill i can run the motor with PWM

Comment: and regarding the Vgs ,, i think it's not the issue as with the same half bridge i controlled a 1000W brushed DC motor at full load and the mosfets withstand the load

Comment: Can you measure any overstress in the SOA during OFF transitions?  Perhaps a TVS is needed or read this https://e2e.ti.com/blogs_/b/motordrivecontrol/archive/2015/06/30/simplifying-gate-driver-design-for-brushed-dc-motors

Comment: Does adding diodes in parallel with the mosfets increase the voltage spikes ?? the diodes are not fast recovery diodes,, Thank you for your answers it's really helpful

Comment: Yes the diode capacitance will add surge current and must be low C fast type like TVS

Comment: but does the body diodes of IRF540 will be enough for the motor current to flow through when the mosfets are off? ,, we choose to put large current capacity diode in parallel with the mosfets to handle this current flow in the small period of time when all mosfets are off,, Is that wrong?